# Save etire webpage as PDF with jsPDF

Tags: pdf, printing, jspdf

I need a button on the webpage that immediately saves the page to PDF with the same `@media print` css. So it looks exactly like the print page function.

I had a look at jsPDF and tried the code down below. But **I got the following error** when trying to select the whole webpage:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

**It must be in my selection** of the entire webpage:

```
source = $("html").html();
```

**My code:**

```
<script>
    function demoFromHTML() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
        // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
        source = $("html").html();

        // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
        // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
        // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
        // (class, of compound) at this time.
        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
        // 'inches' in this case
        pdf.fromHTML(
        source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, { // y coord
            'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },

        function (dispose) {
            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            pdf.save('Test.pdf');
        }, margins);
    }
//</script>
<a href="javascript:demoFromHTML()" class="button">Save as PDF</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well You have some rowspan or Colspan there in your html try removing those and it will work fine or try using this line

```
while (j < tableRow.cells.length) {
```

instead of this one in your jspdf file

```
while (j < tableRow.cells.length && headers[j] != undefined) {
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Sorry I marked it correct many years later. Your upvote on my question is much appreciated!! : D